# How to modify default filter logic of mat-table to only filter for visible table values

Tags: angular, mat-table

I am using a mat-table and the default filter seems to also search for fields that are not visible but exist in my dataSource object.

My Object consists of following properties:

- Id: string
- description: string
- srcStep: string
- dstStep: string

Applying 
`this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (data: MyDataSource, filter: string) => data.description.trim().toLowerCase().indexOf(filter) != -1;`
seems to work fine for one column.

How can I modify filterPredicate to also check for srcStep but not for dstStep

Answer (score 0):

I didn't think it would be as easy as this but I've found a solution that fits my needs.
Just check for every column one by one and return true if the filter applies to this column.

```
this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (data: MyDataSource, filter: string) => {
      if (data.description.trim().toLowerCase().indexOf(filter) !== -1) return true;
      if (data.srcStep.trim().toLowerCase().indexOf(filter) !== -1) return true;
    }
```